# remove hyperlink on a username in discussion boards list page

Tags: sharepoint-2007

i am having a discussion board. and when we access that discussion board, the default view is flat view. in that view there will be "Posted By" field. On clicking the image or username on that field, sp will redirects to the corresponding user page(about details). in my current project i want to disable all this posted by field. just i want to show picture of the user and username, no hyperlink.
how to do this? its very urgent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Removing the hyper link would not be possible unless until you create the custom webpart for the same; work around could be to disable the hyper links by changing their href by # using JavaScript which would be called below the web part in HTML

Comment: thanks Ashutosh. Can you help me regarding hiding the Actions menu from discussion board list. I have tried different javascript functions, but no use..I am new to sharepoint.

Comment: You can use the below script but iw ould suggest to use custom master page in which you just remove site action or apply a sharepoint trim control so that it is visible to administrator only<script type="text/javascript" >
this.document.getElementById("siteactiontd").style.display = 'none';
</script>

Comment: thanks ashutosh. I have a doubt regarding sharepoint login. When i accessing a sharepoint site, it prompts for the user to enter username and password. If he clicks cancel button, the page is hsowing 401:unauthorized. I want to redirect the page to home(welcome)page when he clicks cancel button. how to achieve this?

Comment: This is a default behavior of share point you can follow the below URL and write some JavaScript to redirect to a page you want http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sridhara/archive/2007/04/14/customizing-placeholder-values-in-moss-2007.aspx

Comment: thanks Ashutosh. I am redirecting the user to home(welcome) page after the user clicks signout button. I am doing successfully the operation but the problem is that it shows the user who clikced signout is not logged out. I am using this code:

Comment: function _spBodyOnLoad() { try { document.execCommand("ClearAuthenticationCache");  window.location=home page url; } catch (e) {}
}      i want to show the site without user logged in(anonymous)

Comment: Hi I'm not sure with Firefox as firefox comes under level 2 browser support category for MOSS 2007. So it might happen that few things which are supported in IE may not work at the same in Firefox.